# How to set a type depends on function arguments in typescript?

Tags: typescript

**My test code**

```
type Config = {
  id: string;
  password: string;
}

type TrueTypeConfig = Config & {
  emailId: number;
  paymentId: number;
}

type FalseTypeConfig = Config & {
  documentId: number;
  buyerId: number;
}

type GetTestConfig<T extends boolean> = (type: T, id: string, password: string)
  => T extends true
    ? TrueTypeConfig
    : FalseTypeConfig
    
function getTestConfig<T extends boolean> (type: T, id: string, password: string): T extends true ? TrueTypeConfig : FalseTypeConfig;
function getTestConfig (type: boolean, id: string, password: string): TrueTypeConfig | FalseTypeConfig {
  const config: TrueTypeConfig | FalseTypeConfig = {
    id: getRandomData(id),
    password: getRandomData(password),
  };
  if (type) {
    config.emailId = getRandomNumber(1, 100);
    config.paymentId = getRandomNumber(1, 100);
  } else {
    config.documentId = getRandomNumber(1, 100);
    config.buyerId = getRandomNumber(1, 100);
  }
  return config;
};

const res1 = getTestConfig(false, '1', '1'); // FalseTypeConfig
const res2 = getTestConfig(true, '1', '1'); // TrueTypeConfig
```

"getTestconfig" function has to return ConfigType True or False config. It depends on an argument "type". (It's working with the above test code)
But `const config: TrueTypeConfig | FalseTypeConfig` is type error and also inside if/else codes too.

**My question**

- Is the above test code common method for set a return type of function, when it depends on arguments?
- I don't know how to fix the type issue `const config: TrueTypeConfig | FalseTypeConfig`

I wanna know better way "how to define return type"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using a generic [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) this way as a function return is perfectly fine.  As you've noticed, the compiler is unfortunately unable to verify that a particular value inside the function implementation is assignable to such a conditional type dependent on an unspecified generic type parameter; this is the topic of [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912).  Until and unless that issue is addressed, you will have to shift some of the burden of type safety from the compiler to you, such as with [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions), or, as you've done, a single-call signature [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads).

---

As for the implementation of `getTestConfig()`, you can't say that `config` is a `TrueTypeConfig | FalseTypeConfig` because it doesn't have enough properties to start with.  At best you could say it's type `Config` and then later *narrow* it to one of the desired types.

Instead of initializing `config` in stages, which is hard for the compiler to verify,  I would just use something like [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) or [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) to initialize `config` all at once:

```
function getTestConfig<T extends boolean>(type: T, id: string, password: string): T extends true ? TrueTypeConfig : FalseTypeConfig;
function getTestConfig(type: boolean, id: string, password: string): TrueTypeConfig | FalseTypeConfig {
  return {
    id: getRandomData(id),
    password: getRandomData(password),
    ...(type ?
      {
        emailId: getRandomNumber(1, 100),
        paymentId: getRandomNumber(1, 100)
      } : {
        documentId: getRandomNumber(1, 100),
        buyerId: getRandomNumber(1, 100)
      }
    )
  };
}
```

That should compile cleanly.

---

The only other way I can imagine to do a return type that depends on input parameters more safely (which precludes overloads entirely) is to try to use a [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) for the return.  I tried this and it's really ugly/impenetrable and relies on coercing `boolean` values to their equivalent `string` via TS4.1's [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types).  I won't even include the code in the text here, since I don't recommend it.  It's included in the Playground link below if you really care, and I'm happy to explain it if you want.  But I'd say that a generic conditional type is probably the best solution for now.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwHMQMAlKVYHAWwBEoMoAKADwC55yBPASnYGcMMLKgIBuAFChIsBCnTY8hYmQrUAcsioAjEDBbsuAGnicDqHu1SadMCeIycADggDCeRFgLwAvPADe4vDwWMD8gsJigfCOUHx8AO44MKHwAkIiEgC+4vZOCAAqMMgg+XluqB5evuWV8ABk-lEgVFBYEACSKVbauhJBMZxUIKgYnZbWveLZuc7wAGJQEHwlZe6ePvA16w0BQZRgmsOjXRO2UVrInLpj8N02WTkOswDixPkgAlsEADz58CDMDDDYB8eBaHA4CAgcgAPg2jCeIHY+WMITC6QIxhicUSyXREW4UW8cL+AKBFFBgmK8CiAH54IViqVnF8ouwFksViy1gQcnJMLh8EQMO9Pjzfv9AcDQeDIdDUDCEXlkaiUmkIljYgkkmrwiJeAzJeSQfAqQh6YyuSAvvB2YtlszrTyJPyFEK3h8MF8lc52LKoeRVfiRJqcTrgwQDZbHTaAD7ze1Wm27eBwDDIGD4FNBNFKUjkSi0ehMELcQxRfpa3EpYUqQt0BiMbHa5JlivwAB0XZ95vbQWzQUHzVaHRrygL6lOjAAjMZpwAGedtwcr6JQQZHG61idUDQ9PSz+ALpd9+CZW2NVeD-aHEZb8eqXdTw-H5dXsGXa5j-OPvc2GdzouhJXtkK7AWeDziGAeACKmHzThswqil6PKMIgibGAA5NOmFYTh3CiPAAD0REJpyMY8lBMEYHBfAAEyIR6YoVJ4CJFCAeG4fA2GYQRxGkdGqwsby4ioFAQx8DEYAIAAsuuOiNFEiIMnkcmOBsA5msi7EUcJ5YruhnJ2uRQmVFE0xBK6gqmjgADKeo-KSUoUqkDnwPGdy6O5YIQgGCoIsiBoAAYACR+PkmRBZeg5phm+D2RiCLcBwoJcH0Z45JZaACooSGel8EpktKPlyrCPYqsEuoYqGLZVQSyKqVAjgANqheFkUALrRUE0GoLBvW1L4A45t+dbUA2JbAG+K7NtW7Dbo+E1NlWOrTRB7axZm3WDsKprsYwyXDTFxBxdtV7Dm094-oWf66ABR5Afp76Vhud6jTut0HoBS5Pc9XYdgNninkEmTpSumS-TtxBIImB1ncd6ZbUdK43kMb3zQ+N3Pt9a1XhcVwwFdY1Pvu92vpDV7-YDvLPaDp4Q+2mTNRgdkOT23AdelFnwL1sFwHwCG+HlzGVGhGHcThnF8SRZEOqZQM9dRtEMULTEocJbHFJxUuETLgncsJOSZEAA)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer with related post link and I'm happy that my test way is fine.
I didn't know about the typescript issue [microsfot/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) before I check it. I was just feeling something strange and I had a doubt if my way about defining return type is fine.
Now everything is clear by your answer. Thx a lot. :)

Comment: And the other way about TS4.1's template literal types, I checked the code in Playground link. It seemed like I needed to code more unnecessary code to define the type.
I totally agree. at your last words "A generic conditional type is probably the best solution for now"